# Show div elements in a single line when screen size is reduced

Tags: css

Is it possible to make header content to display in one single row at any point of time with reduced screen size and instead get a scroll bar when screen size is reduced.

```
Here's the link of my page header looks like: http://codepen.io/vengal-learn/pen/QGJdze
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox layout is what you're looking for. This should get you started :-)

This site should help you... https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```
#header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
}
#headerLeft {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

#headerCenter {
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

#headerRight {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it's working for me. Only issue is the min IE version to be used in my project is 8. So trying to find a work around for this. Thank you!

Comment: You're going to be hard pressed to find an easy way to do it for older versions of IE. At that point I would say it's a question of how many of your users are using IE8 and if it's even worth making your site back compat.

It's important to remember that anything older than IE 9 is no longer supported meaning if this is a policy from your company or customer, you may want recommend to them to move to a more secure version like IE9 or higher, Chrome or Firefox. If they don't they are likely going to have security holes in their systems.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know!